# symfony how to translate validation messages with expression

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I´m trying to translate a validation message that uses expression  like GreaterThan() validation constrain class.

How can I translate this message "This value should be greater than {comparator_value}." ?

Other simple messages without expression it´s working fine

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to get the min value of GreaterThan. You must replace {comparator_value} with {{ compared_value }}, it will look like below:

```
This value should be greater than {{ compared_value }}
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks for answer me, but my problem is when I define the translation file like this 
This value should be greater than {{ compared_value }} : Any other language translation {{ compared_value }}

Then when I use the $translator->trans($msg) $msg has already parsed and {{ compared_value }} has been replaced by the value I defined so I cannot translate, but if I configure for example my translatior  file like this "This value should be greater than 5" instead, it works.

Comment: You can not use $translator->trans method, you must create a file named validations.yml in your bundle translation folder or in app/resources/translations folders to translate. If you use translation file, you need to add message="trans_key" params into your annotation assertion: GreaterThan(5, message="trans_key").